# Highlighting mismatched cells using vba

Tags: vba, excel

In excel sheet 1 I have a column named **phonetype** which has some strings in each cell.

I have sheet 2 in the same excel workbook with column name **allowed phonetype** and some strings in each cell.

Now I want to compare if the strings in `Phonetype` column of **sheet 1** are the same as the strings in `allowed phonetype` column of **sheet 2**; If not highlight those cells.

Everything using vba.

```
   Sheet 1                            Sheet 2
column name:"Phonetype"             columnname:"allowed phone type"
cell 1:welcome                      cell 1:welcome
cell 2:                             cell 2:hi121
cell 3:heythere
cell 4:hi121
```

the string "heythere" is not present in sheet 2(column:"allowed phone type"), so that should be highlighted

Comment: what have you done? What is not working? Post code and you should show what you have tried. Just so you know, pretty similar questions like this have been asked and answered many times before so try the search function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here something to get you started*

```
Option Explicit
'// Campare and Hilight Unique
Sub CompareHighlightUnique()
    Dim Range1      As Range
    Dim Range2      As Range
    Dim i           As Integer
    Dim j           As Integer
    Dim isMatch     As Boolean

    For i = 2 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        isMatch = False
        Set Range1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
        For j = 1 To Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
           Set Range2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & j)
           If StrComp(Trim(Range1.Text), Trim(Range2.Text), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                isMatch = True
                Exit For
            End If
            Set Range2 = Nothing
        Next j
        If Not isMatch Then
            Range1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
        Set Range1 = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub
```

*To change the highlight color edit `RGB(255, 0, 0)`*

*to change the sheet1 or sheet2 edit `("Sheet1") and ("Sheet2")`*

Answer (score 0):

Check it out,,

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, a As Range
    Dim Rws2 As Long, rng2 As Range, c As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws
        Rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rws, 1))
        Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End With

    With sh
        Rws2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng2 = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rws2, 1))
    End With

    For Each a In Rng.Cells
        For Each c In rng2.Cells
            If a = c Then a.Interior.Color = xlNone
        Next c
    Next a

End Sub
```

[Found here,](http://www.xlorate.com/excel-vba-loops.html)

Comment: In sheet 2, i have a column named "allowed phonetype" which contains a list of  strings eg. cell 1=abc,cell2=def etc. Now, in sheet 1 under the column "phonetype", the cells contain strings like cell 1=abc,cell 3= ghf etc. I have to highlight the cells if the strings in sheet 1 are not equal to any of the strings in sheet 2. Can you please modify your code?

Comment: please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474144/how-to-loop-through-numbers-in-vba?noredirect=1#comment49039212_30474144